# Why pg_restore of BLOB-s is so slow and how can this be improved?

Tags: postgresql

I have locally a 2 GB database dump with BLOB-s, in "custom" pg_dump format. It takes about 50 minutes to restore, 49 of which is restoring the BLOB-s.

PostgreSQL version is 8.4.2. Platforms: OS X & Linux

Can the restoration time be somehow improved?

Answer (score 2):

Restoring large amounts of binary data is an inherently time-consuming process, and Postgres is about as efficient at it as a database server can be.

In order to speed up the restore you basically need faster disks.

Answer (score 0):

Stop saving the images in the database, just save the path instead.

Comment: How do you know he's storing images? There is nothing in the question that supports this assumption...